# Check all values in another column (NULL or NOT NULL ) and return unique records

Tags: sql

[image]

As you see for cid=1 all date fields are NULL and for cid=3 all date fields are NOT NULL.

I need get unique cids with new field, if all dates are NULL then with "NULL" and if all dates are NOT NULL then with "NOT NULL".

```
cid - new field
1 - NULL
3 - NOT NULL
```

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: which database are you using.

Comment: I use postgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and `case`:

```
select cid,
       (case when count(datecol) = 0 then 'NULL'
             when count(datecol) = count(*) then 'NOT NULL'
        end) as newField
from t
group by cid
having count(datecol) in (0, count(*));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select cid, case when min(c) = 0 AND max(c) = 0 then 'null' when min(c) = 1 and max(c) = 1 then 'not null' end from (
    select cid, case when dt is null then 0 else 1 end as c from your_table
) t
group by cid
having min(c) = max(c)
```